# While executing an express application it crashed

Tags: javascript, port

```
node .\\index.js
node:events:490
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
at Server.setupListenHandle \[as \_listen2\] (node:net:1774:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1822:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1910:7)
at Function.listen (D:\\Gamaca AI\\Express2\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\application.js:635:24)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (D:\\Gamaca AI\\Express2\\index.js:9:5)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1801:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3000
}

Node.js v19.8.1
```

```sh
$ node index.js
```

We tried to execute from this command.

###### Check it Out the code !

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (res, req) => {
  res.send("Hello Rushikesh! ");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("App is lodding in Port no 3000 !");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in question.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

The port 3000 already in use.
You need to kill all process for this port before running your express or any app which use 3000 port.

##### For windows

Find PID of your process.

```
netstat -aon | findstr 3000
```

It will reponse like this message

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2980
  TCP    [::]:3000             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2980
```

then kill process

```
taskkill /f /pid 2980
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your port 3000 is available or try to run it on a different port.